# jquery sum and addclass

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

Pulling my hair out over this...  In short - I have 2 fields and a div that displays the sum of those fields.  If the person adjusts the amount and the amount does not equal the original amount then I change the class to "sumbad".  If the person changes the amount so it equals the original amount then I want to change the class to "sumgood".  I have everything working except reverting back to "sumgood".  Any help is appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".txt1").each(function(){
    $(this).keyup(function(){calculateSum1();
    });
   });
  });
  function calculateSum1()
  {var sum=0;$(".txt1").each(function(){
   
   if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
              sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            $(this).css("background-color", "#FEFFB0");
   }
   else if (this.value.length != 0){
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
   }
  });
  
  $("#sum1").html(sum);  
  var finalinventory1 = '48'; 
  
   if ($("#sum1").html(sum)!= 48) {
    $("#sum1").addClass('sumbad').removeClass('sumgood');
   }
   
   else if ($("#sum1").html(sum) === 48) {
    $("#sum1").addClass('sumgood').removeClass('sumbad');
    alert("Your book is overdue.");
   }
  }
```

```css
.sumgood{
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#060
}
.sumbad{
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#900
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Available Retail:
<input type="text" name="available1"  class="txt1" value="29" size="5" ><br>
Available Wholesale:
<input type="text" name="availablewholesale1"  class="txt1" value="19" size="5" ><br>
Original Inventory: 48<br>
Adjusted Inventory:
<span class="sumgood" id="sum1">48</span>
```

Here's the jfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/m8cdx5mk/3/

Comment: Did you mean to check if `sum != 48` instead of `$("#sum1").html(sum)!= 48`?

Comment: $("#sum1").html(sum) is the sum of the two text fields with class set to #txt1.  That part is working (but I'm 99.9% certain someone with better jquery skills than me could significantly shorten it.)

Comment: Well, `console.log($("#sum1").html(sum))`. The return value won't be a number, so comparing that result to `48` wouldn't do any good. I think the value of `sum` is the sum of the two text fields, so that's what you want to compare with `48`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use text() instead of html()
here's the correct code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".txt1").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function() {
            calculateSum1();
        });
    });
});

function calculateSum1() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".txt1").each(function() {

        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            $(this).css("background-color", "#FEFFB0");
        } else if (this.value.length != 0) {
            $(this).css("background-color", "red");
        }
    });

    $("#sum1").html(sum);
    var finalinventory1 = '48';

    if ($("#sum1").text() != '48') {
        $("#sum1").addClass('sumbad').removeClass('sumgood');
    } else if ($("#sum1").text() === '48') {
        $("#sum1").addClass('sumgood').removeClass('sumbad');
        alert("Your book is overdue.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why check `$("#sum1").text()` when you set the HTML of `$("#sum1")` to `sum` two lines earlier? Just compare `sum != 48` instead...

Comment: you're right @MMiller. he can just use the value of sum to compare. i just corrected his code. the variable finalinventory1 is also unused.

Comment: Code is kind of hacked together b/c I'm calling it in a loop so all the vars are dynamically generated.  Will clean it up once it's running.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of performance and organization improvements that could be made, so I rewrote some of it to better take advantage of memory and optimization.

```
$(function () {
    var $fields = $('.txt1');
    var $sum1 = $('#sum1');

    $fields.keyup(function calculateSum1 () {
        var sum = 0;
        $fields.each(function () {
            var $field = $(this);

            var value = this.value;
            if (value.length) {
                value = parseFloat(value);
                if (!isNaN(value)) {
                    sum += value;
                    $field.css('background-color', '#FEFFB0');
                } else {
                    $field.css('background-color', 'red');
                }
            }
        });

        $sum1.html(sum);

        var finalinventory1 = 48;

        $sum1.removeClass('sumgood sumbad');
        if (sum != finalinventory1) {
            $sum1.addClass('sumgood');
            alert('Your book is overdue.');
        } else {
            $sum1.addClass('sumbad');
        }
    });
});
```